# Referring global variable with AsmJit

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, asmjit

I need to to load an address of an existing global variable/ exernal variable to a register with a lea operation. Is this possible in AsmJit? The associated ptr function only seem to accept GpVar which needs to be created within AsmJit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. The most portable and recommended way would be to use *mov reg, imm*:

```
using namespace asmjit;
using namespace asmjit::host;

// You have to initialize these...
Compiler c;

GpVar var(c, kVarTypeIntPtr);

void* p = NULL;
c.mov(var, imm_ptr(p));
```

Or *lea reg, mem* having an absolute address [mem] form. This solution works as expected only in 32-bit mode; the absolute address size is always truncated to 32 bits:

```
c.lea(var, ptr_abs(p));
```